# No Hash Partitioning when using repartition in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, hadoop-partitioning

The spark [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) says that `.repartition()` returns a new DataFrame, which is by default `Hash-Partitioned`. But, in the example I am running, as shown below, that's not the case.

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([('a',22),('b',1),('c',4),('b',1),('d',2),
                    ('a',0),('d',3),('a',1),('c',4),('b',7),
                    ('a',2),('a',22),('b',1),('c',4),('b',1),
                    ('d',2),('a',0),('d',3),('a',1),('c',4),
                    ('b',7),('a',2)] 
                   )
df=rdd.toDF(['key','value'])
df=df.repartition(5,'key')    #5 partitions on 'key' column
print("Partitioner: {}".format(df.rdd.partitioner)) # prints - 'Partitioner: None'  Why??
```

Why I don't have a partitioner? Let me print the partitions using `glom()` function -

```
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(df.rdd.glom().collect()))
[
 [ #Partition 1
   Row(key='a', value=22), Row(key='a', value=0), Row(key='a', value=1), 
   Row(key='a', value=2), Row(key='a', value=22), Row(key='a', value=0), 
   Row(key='a', value=1), Row(key='a', value=2)
 ], 

 [ #Partition 2
   Row(key='b', value=1), Row(key='b', value=1), Row(key='b', value=7), 
   Row(key='b', value=1), Row(key='b', value=1), Row(key='b', value=7)
 ], 

 [ #Partition 3
   Row(key='c', value=4), Row(key='c', value=4), Row(key='c', value=4),
   Row(key='c', value=4)
 ],

 [ #Partition 4 (empty)
 ],

 [ #Partition 5
  Row(key='d', value=2), Row(key='d', value=3), Row(key='d', value=2),
  Row(key='d', value=3)
 ]
]
```

We can clearly see that the data is well partitioned by `key`, with all `Rows()` with same `key` column ending on one partition. So, why does the `partitioner` prints `None`?
What can I do so as to have a `partitioner`, which can further be used for optimization?

Comment: `RDD` is not `DataFrame` and `DataFrame` partitioning (`df._jdf.queryExecution().toRdd().partitioner()`) cannot be used to _logically_ optimize execution on `RDD`, same as `RDD` partitioning has no impact on logical optimization of SQL plan, when `RDD` is converted to `DataFrame`. For `DataFrame` operations your good, as is.

Comment: Thank you for your response and referring me to the appropriate link. Regards,